# J2EE seguridad y sessiones

Tags: java, jsf, ejb

Estoy utilizando `jdbc-realm` y la configuración apropiada de `web.xml`  para proteger con autentificacion ciertos recursos.
El formulario utilizo etiquetas `j_security_check` ,`j_username` y `j_password`.

Protegerlas las protege bien pero si intento hacer login , sin digamos atacar al recurso protegido me salta un error de

```
Estado http 400 Referencia directa al formulario de conexión (página de formulario de login) inválida
```

Es decir, no me redirige al recurso , que por el rol de usuario, debería ir. Uso `jsf` y `EJB`  y soy totalmente nuevo con estas tecnologías.

¿Alguien me podría decir qué me falta o qué hago mal?

Comment: Puede mostrar código ? para saber en qué puede estar fallando.

Answer (score 2):

Cuando se utiliza un `jdbcRealm`, es bueno utilizar *seguridad administrada por el contenedor*, i.e., `container-managed-security` para autenticación y autorización de recursos en su app. en vez de manipularlo desde el propio código aunque dependiendo de los requerimientos, puede que sea necesario y hay otra forma de delegar el "login" al servidor de aplicaciones.

El servidor es quien se hará cargo de autenticar y autorizar usuarios dependiendo de su **rol** en la aplicación. y para activar el *servlet* que se encarga de éste proceso, hay que crear un formulario **html** según la [especificación del Servlet](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19226-01/820-7627/bncby/index.html):

el formulario debe ir en una página separada que normalmente sólo contiene el formulario para iniciar sesión:

Luego en el `Descriptor de Despliegue` (web.xml) debemos agregar la configuración que le dirá al servidor:

- cuáles son los recursos (páginas, folders) que serán restringidos
  dependiendo del **rol** del usuario
- Establecemos los roles exsistentes
- Establecemos la ruta de la página de inicio de sesión
- Establecemos la protección de la informacion (SSL)

**web.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" 
         xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">    


<security-constraint>
    <display-name>Restricción 1</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>resources</web-resource-name>
        <description />            
        <url-pattern>/protected/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>appUser</role-name>
        <role-name>appAdmin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>appRealm</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/index.xhtml</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/public/forbidden.xhtml</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>


<security-role>
    <role-name>appUser</role-name>
</security-role>


<security-role>
    <role-name>appAdmin</role-name>
</security-role>   

<error-page>
    <error-code>403</error-code>
    <location>/public/forbidden.xhtml</location>
</error-page>

</web-app>
```

Ahora hay que mapear los roles con los grupos de la base de datos y ésto depende mucho del Servidor que se esté utilizando, para éste ejemplo lo hago con `Glassfish`

creamos un archivo `glassfish-web.xml` o `sun-web.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE sun-web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.0 Servlet 3.0//EN" "http://www.sun.com/software/appserver/dtds/sun-web-app_3_0-0.dtd">
<sun-web-app error-url="">

    <security-role-mapping>
        <role-name>appUser</role-name>
        <group-name>1</group-name>
    </security-role-mapping>

    <security-role-mapping>
        <role-name>appAdmin</role-name>
        <group-name>2</group-name>
    </security-role-mapping>

  <class-loader delegate="true"/>
  <jsp-config>
    <property name="keepgenerated" value="true">
      <description>Keep a copy of the generated servlet class' java code.</description>
    </property>
  </jsp-config>
</sun-web-app>
```

Ahora creamos la base de datos que va a contener la info para que ésto funcione:

```
CREATE TABLE `tabla_usuarios`(

    correo VARCHAR(255),
    pwd VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,    
    PRIMARY KEY (correo)

)ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET UTF8;


CREATE TABLE grupos(

    correo VARCHAR(255),
    grupo  VARCHAR(30), 
    PRIMARY KEY(correo)

)ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET UTF8;
```

Estos serían los requisitos mínimos para la DB.

Lo único que falta ahora es crear el `realm` (reino) en el servidor.

Abrimos la consola de administración, `localhost:4848` y vamos a:

```
Configurations >> Server-Config >> Security >> Realms
```

Creamos un nuevo realm:

1. El nombre debe ser igual al establecido en  realm-name
2. Seleccionamos del `select` la opción que tiene jdbcRealm

Luego llenamos las casillas con la información correspondiente:

- JAAS Context = jdbcRealm
- JNDI = nombre_jndi (en glassfish-resources.xml se encuentra)
- User Table = tabla_usuarios
- User Name Column = tabla_usuarios.correo
- Password Column = tabla_usuarios.pwd
- Group Table = grupos
- Group Table User Name Column = grupos.correo
- Group Name Column = grupos.grupo
- Password Encryption Algorithm = SHA-256
- Datablase User = usuario_para_accesso_a_db
- Database Password = contraseña_usuario_db

El resto de las casillas pueden dejarse en blanco pero hay que tener una cosa en cuenta, a partir de `Glassfish 4.+` éste nos obliga a utilizar un algoritmo para encriptar las contraseñas, por lo que yo he puesto `SHA-256` ahora para guardar usuarios hay que guardar las contraseñas en `SHA-256` al momento de registrarlos para que `JAAS` funcione.

Para encriptar:

```
public static String encriptar(String contrasena) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException{

    byte[] bytes = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256").digest(contrasena.getBytes());

    return DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(bytes).toLowerCase();
}
```